# Seamless Cube Maps on OpenGL ES 2.0 using iOS?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Is there an equivalent for

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS);
```

in OpenGL ES2.0 when implementing cubemap samplers? I'm developing a test app on the iPad -- cubemapping a sphere -- and I'm getting seams between each face of the cubemap.

Or if there is no magic glEnable for ES2.0, what is the best way to get rid of the seams?

Comment: Oops, I found the solution already. Just setting "CLAMP_TO_EDGE" in both directions works! glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL ES does not have the equivalent of desktop GL's ARB_seamless_cube_map functionality.

And no, `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S/T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)` does not count. Seamless cubemapping means that texels from different faces can be blended together. Clamping to the edge means exactly that: clamping to the *edge* of a face. What you've done is make the seam less noticeable; it's still *there*.

Comment: This doesn't seem accurate on Android using OpenGL ES 2.0 on PowerVR -- I used GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP without clamping and there were no seams, and there was blending between the textures. Is it driver specific?

Comment: @Kevin: The specification does not allow for it to blend across images. If it does, then that's off-spec behavior. Obviously not unwelcome, but off-spec nevertheless.

Comment: Did you're cubemap itself have seems? Most don't so you won't seams anyways